# Error loading external lua module (luasql.postgres) from module imbedded in C++ project

Tags: c++, c, postgresql, lua

I need to write a C++ project with a Lua script, which reads info from PostgreSQL and gives recieved data back to C++ project. 
It works correctly when called from terminal with Lua-interpreter however when I try to call Lua module from C++, script works incorrectly and returns error.

Home OS - Debian 9.
PostgreSQL version - 9.6.
Compiler - g++.
Lua version - 5.3.4.
I've already tried changing  in Lua file trying different *.so files. It didn't help.

Compiler/Linker flags:

> g++ -c -m64 -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I.
>   -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o main.o
>
> g++ -m64 -o luaTest main.o -llua -ldl

main.cpp

```
lua_State* _script = luaL_newstate();
if (_script == NULL) {
    std::cout << "Failed to allocate memory!\n";
    return -1;
}
int result = luaL_loadfile(_script, filename1);
if (result != LUA_OK) {
    std::cout << "Failed to load file!\n";
    return -1;
}
luaL_openlibs(_script);
result = lua_pcall(_script, 0, 0, 0);
if (result != LUA_OK) {
    std::string luaError = lua_tostring(_script, -1);
    std::cout << "Failed to run script!\n" << luaError << '\n';
    return -1;
}
```

lua:

```
package.cpath = "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.3-sql-postgres.so"

function getDatabase()
    driver = require "luasql.postgres"
    env = assert(driver.postgres())

connect = assert(env:connect("luabase", "sorokin", "123456", "127.0.0.1", "5432"))

res = connect:execute("DROP SEQUENCE user_ids")
res = connect:execute("DROP TABLE users")


res = assert(connect:execute("CREATE TABLE users(\
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,\
                fname CHAR(15),\
                lname CHAR(30),\
                job CHAR(15)\
                )"))

res = assert(connect:execute("INSERT INTO users(id, fname, lname, job) \
            VALUES (1, 'Andrey', 'Sedin', 'Deputat')"))
res = assert(connect:execute("INSERT INTO users \
            VALUES (2, 'Andrey', 'Dranga', 'Boxer')"))
res = assert(connect:execute("INSERT INTO users \
            VALUES (3, 'Roberto', 'Ierusalimskiy', 'Programmer')"))



cursor = assert(connect:execute("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY lname"))

print()
print(string.format("%1s %-16s %-31s %-16s",
        "#", "| FNAME", "| LNAME", "| JOB"))
print(string.format("%1s %-16s %-31s %-16s",
        "-", "| -----", "| -----", "| ---"))

row = cursor:fetch({}, "a")
while row do
    print(string.format("%1s %1s %-15s%1s %-30s%1s %-15s",
        row.id, "|", row.fname, "|", row.lname, "|", row.job))
    row = cursor:fetch(row, "a")
end
print()

cursor:close()
connect:close()
env:close()
end

getDatabase()
```

error message from Lua-script:

> error loading module 'luasql.postgres' from file
>   '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.3-sql-postgres.so':
>     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.3-sql-postgres.so: undefined
>   symbol: lua_settop

Comment: My best guess is a version mismatch, make sure that you're using the same version of Lua (5.3) everywhere. Maybe your C++ project is using a different version of Lua (use `print(_VERSION)` to see the Lua version you're running on.

Comment: Having your compiler and linker options would help. Same goes to seeing your includes. Similar errors usually occur in C++ if you don't include lua headers within `extern "C"`.

Comment: You need to export the Lua API symbols from your C++ program. Link it with `-Wl,-E`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I actually solved the problem.
Version was correct and the error wasn't about includes as well.
I believe Lua wasn't exporting API symbols correctly as @Ihf said, but I think I did something wrong because -Wl,-E didn't work for me either.
I had to explicitly link **liblua5.3.so** for everything to work.

Comment: @RuAlastor I suggest you modify question with your initial compiler/linker flags and post an answer with your own solution. For future reference and the ones curious for more details (like me). Someone may even suggest then a nicer solution if there is one.